# Azure MVC ServiceConfiguration.cscfg change after deployment

Tags: model-view-controller, deployment, azure, web-config, config

I've added a setting to ServiceConfiguration.cscfg with the idea that it will allow me to turn on/off a feature of the MVC app. The code correctly reads the setting however while running the app in local dev compute emulator, I don't see the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file in the .csx directory. I only see the ServiceDefinition.csdef file which has the key but not the value. I want to change the value.

The idea is that I have a text file I can alter after deploying that will allow me to turn on/off parts of the app by opening text file on Azure and making changes.

I don't want to be dependent on Azure Storage or a hop off the Azure box.

What is the best way to change my own app config setting in azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

Your path is correct. ServiceConfiguration.cscfg is one of the places where you could have **service wide** settings. And there is one gotcha here, you can't dynamically change the service configuration with local Azure emulator. If you want to change something in the service configuration, you have to stop your debugging session, change the setting and start new session. Only in live Azure Environment, you can change the service configuration, and it will be propageted to all instances.

I intentionally bolded service wide settings. With full IIS mode (available since SDK 1.3) you can have multiple web sites per single Web Role. That would mean multuple applications. Now I would not want to mess setting for one of the applications, with settings for the other. That is why I would put an **application wide** settings in an Azure Table. And your application may query this table every N seconds/minutes, depends what is your targeted response time.

I wonder what are your thought begind the "I don't want to be dependend on Azure Storage" statement? Before all, you are developing application for the Windows Azure platform. Ain't you going to have any dynamic data? File uploads or file generation or anything like that? Check out the [Windows Azure Storage SLA](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6656). I don't think a Windows Azure storage (in your case I suggest Tables) would be in any harm for your application. Especially when your service deployment is in the same geographic region as your storage account.

Comment: Astaykov, great answer. I didn't realize debug/local computer was different than Cloud in handling the config files. I would rather have a single methodology/location for the config settings so I will put it in an Azure Table.